# "Directly enter debugging when error appears" message in Spyder doesn't work when I run it on a cell

Tags: python, debugging, cell, spyder

I have a question regarding the debugging mode in Spyder:
Under ***Tools -> preferences -> Run*** I checked "Directly enter debugging when error appears". This works pretty well when I run the whole script. For example:

```
def divide_by(a):
    c=a-2
    return 3/c

divide_by(2)
```

Because of division by zero, Spyder throws an error and jumps to debugging mode

```
****************************************
Entering post mortem debugging...
****************************************
> /home/test.py(3)divide_by()
      1 def divide_by(a):
      2     c=a-2
----> 3     return 3/c
      4 
      5 

IPdb[1]:
```

However, I separated my script into cells (using #%%)
For example:

```
def divide_by(a):
    c=a-2
    return 3/c

#%%
divide_by(2)
```

When I only execute the last cell (means only this line: `divide_by(2)` by pressing the "run current cell" button), Spyder is throwing an error because of the division by zero, but it doesn't jump to debugging mode.

Is there any possibility that the "Directly enter debugging when error appears"- functionality in Spyder also works when only a cell and not the whole script is executed?

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I think that option just allows you to enter debug mode when running the whole file as you said. Maybe you could use the `Debug cell` funtionality (`Debug > Debug cell`)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your comment! My code includes iterating through a very long list, while my function is called for every iteration step. For most entries of the list my function works fine but not for all. Using the Debug cell functionality provided by spyder, would mean that I need to go line by line through my for-loop, till an error appears (maybe 1000 times or more...). This is why I want spyder to stop automatically when an error appears, giving me the opportunity to identify the entry of the list which cause the error.